# Mixing 2 queries to display unique coupons PHP/MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct

So I have these 2 tables and I'm trying to write the most efficient query to output the distinct coupons for each manufacturer:

```
Manu Table
manu_id    manu_name
   1        Fujitsu 
   2           HP
   3        Brother

Products Table
prod_id    manu_id    prod_type   prod_coupon_img
    1         2          A4            1.jpg
    2         2         paper          1.jpg
    3         2         boxes          2.jpg
    4         3          ink           3.jpg
```

This query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT m.manu_id, p.prod_id, p.prod_type, p.prod_coupon_img
                    FROM manu m INNER JOIN products p 
                    WHERE m.manu_id=2 AND m.manu_id=p.manu_id");
```

Outputs:

```
prod_id    manu_id    prod_type  prod_coupon_img
    1         2          A4           1.jpg
    2         2         paper         1.jpg
    3         2         boxes         2.jpg
```

and this query:

```
$sqlDistinctCoupons = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT m.manu_id, p.prod_coupon_img 
                                   FROM manu m INNER JOIN products p 
                                   WHERE m.manu_id=2 AND m.manu_id=p.manu_id");
```

Outputs:

```
manu_id    prod_coupon_img
   2            1.jpg
   2            2.jpg
```

What I'm trying to accomplish now is to show the unique coupons HP is offering, so one for (A4 & paper), and one for boxes. 
Here is my code to output that:

```
$DistinctCoupons .=   'Showing coupon for $row["prod_type"] products <img id="$row["prod_id"]" src="$row["prod_coupon_img"]" />';
```

How can I do this, how can I mix both queries to just one and output the distinct coupons? I tried 2 while loops but that didn't work, and I've been reading that you shouldn't use 2 while loops on db calls anyways, as it puts a lot of unneeded strain. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$manu_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['manu_name']);
$query = "SELECT p2.prod_type, p2.prod_id, p2.prod_coupon_img
FROM products p2 
WHERE p2.id IN (
  SELECT Min(p.id)
  FROM products p 
  INNER JOIN manu m ON (m.manu_id = p.manu_id)
  WHERE m.manu_name = '$manu_name'
  GROUP BY prod_coupon_img) ";
```

Comment: note to viewers: Keep in mind that this only works (or is even possible) when case is treated the same way both in the database and on the fileserver, and has been processed as such.  Having a filesystem which considers everything lowercased, with two different sets of casing for an image name, will return two copies of the same coupon.  It is difficult to do a completely cross-platform query for this...